# Display current GPS Location in unity with Bing Maps SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bing-maps

how do i get the gps data displayed on the map? im trying it with the following script but i dont have acess to the latlon values in the mappin script....
i am struggling to access the latlon wrapper so i can change the coordinates.
as i am new to unity and c# i dont get how to dynamically change the values. if i copy the script and change the variables it wont get recognized by the sdk and it doesnt do the work i want... getting the gps data worked so far, as you see in the code. i got the gps data and display it in the game as a text. now i just want to give the mappin.cs my gps data so it can place it in the map. normally i would just add the mappin script to a gameobject, which has to be child of the map and then put in the longtitude and latitude, but as the gps data is not something i can now i dont know how to get i done.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Geospatial;
using Microsoft.Maps.Unity;

public class GPS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text gpsOut;
    public bool isUpdating;
    private double latitude;
    private double longtitude;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isUpdating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetLocation());
            isUpdating = !isUpdating;
        }
       
        Debug.Log(longtitude + " " +  latitude);
        LatLonWrapper position = new LatLonWrapper();
        position.Latitude = latitude;
        position.Longitude = longtitude;
        pin._location = longtitude + " " + latitude);
        pin.Location = position.ToLatLon();


        decalRightSidePos.GetComponent<Decal>().Sprite = decalprefab[index];


    }

    IEnumerator GetLocation()
    {

        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.FineLocation))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.FineLocation);
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation);
        }



        // Check if the user has location service enabled.
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        // Starts the location service.
        Input.location.Start();

        // Waits until the location service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // If the service didn't initialize in 20 seconds this cancels location service use.
        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            gpsOut.text = "Timed out";
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }

        // If the connection failed this cancels location service use.
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            gpsOut.text = "Unable to determine device location";
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            gpsOut.text = "Location" + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            // If the connection succeeded, this retrieves the device's current location and displays it in the Console window.
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
            latitude = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            longtitude = Input.location.lastData.longitude;

        }


        // Stops the location service if there is no need to query location updates continuously.
        isUpdating = !isUpdating;
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#` ..